# Java: String index out of range while checking if a number is a palindrome

Tags: java, string

So, in order to check if a number is a palindrome I converted it to a string. I know there is a similar question on SO but I have already checked that solution, so any help would be appreciated.
Why do I get a `"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException:` ?

My code is here;

```
/*
(Palindrome integer) Write the methods with the following headers

// Return the reversal of an integer, i.e., reverse(456) returns 654
public static int reverse(int number)

// Return true if number is a palindrome
public static boolean isPalindrome(int number)

Use the reverse method to implement isPalindrome. A number is a palindrome
if its reversal is the same as itself. Write a test program that prompts the
user to enter an integer and reports whether the integer is a palindrome.
*/

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = input.nextInt();
        if (isPalindrome(number))
            System.out.println("The number is a palindrome");
        else
            System.out.println("The number is not a palindrome");

    }

    public static int reverse(int number) {
        String reverse = "";
        String n = number + " ";
        for (int i = n.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            reverse += n.charAt(i);
        }

        return Integer.parseInt(reverse);
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
        return number == reverse(number) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the stack trace and the input you give to the program ?

Comment: Why don't you try printing `result` to see if it even is a valid integer

Comment: Hi Massimo, I entered 132

Comment: Your problem is that you did `String n = number + " ";` instead of `String n = number + "";`. You have an extra space. Just remove the space between the quotation marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the reverse function. 
in fact the instruction  `String n = number + " ";` is the concatenation of the value `number` with a blank string. This is not a number and later on gives NomberFormatException at the instruction  `return Integer.parseInt(reverse);` . You should use `String n = Integer.toString(number);`

Here's the reviewed method

```
 public static int reverse(int number) {
    String reverse = "";
    String n = Integer.toString(number); // + " ";
    System.out.println(reverse);
    for (int i = n.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reverse += n.charAt(i);
    }

    return Integer.parseInt(reverse);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the line:

```java
String n = number + " ";
```

for the following:

```java
String n = Integer.toString(number);
```

Because you are trying to parse a *String* with a blank space as last character to an *int*, that is why it throws the *NumberFormatException*.